# help with mysql joins/grouping

Tags: mysql

I'll try to make this simple.

This query lists my sites users, their total orders, cards, and addresses on file.

For some reason if the user has 2 addresses but only 1 order, it will show the customer has 2 orders.

**For example: user4 actually only has 1 order, but shows 2** and im assuming its because he has 2 addresses and it has something to do with the joins or grouping.

```
SELECT
users.user_email,
users.user_firstname,
users.user_lastname,
users.user_joindate,
users.user_logindate,
Count(users_addresses.usera_id) AS count_addr,
Count(users_cards.userc_id) AS count_cards,
Count(orders.order_id) AS count_orders,
Sum(orders.order_total) AS sum_ordertotal
FROM
users
LEFT JOIN users_addresses ON users_addresses.usera_userid = users.user_id
LEFT JOIN users_cards ON users_cards.userc_userid = users.user_id
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.order_userid = users.user_id
GROUP BY
users.user_id
ORDER BY user_id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Example ouput:

```
userid | orders | addresses | cards
------ ----------------------------
user4  |   2    |     2     |   0
user3  |   0    |     0     |   0
user2  |   1    |     1     |   0
user1  |   0    |     1     |   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use COUNT(DISTINCT orders.order_id). However, this doesn't help with the Sum().

Another possibility (albiet less efficient) is to use subqueries for the counts.

```
SELECT
    users.user_email,
    users.user_firstname,
    users.user_lastname,
    users.user_joindate,
    users.user_logindate,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM users_addresses WHERE users_addresses.usera_id = users.user_id) AS count_addr,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM user_cards WHERE users_cards.userc_id = users.user_id) AS count_cards,
    Count(orders.order_id) AS count_orders,
    Sum(orders.order_total) AS sum_ordertotal
FROM users
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.order_userid = users.user_id
GROUP BY users.user_id
ORDER BY user_id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: DISTINCT worked for the counts and it *seems* that it worked for the sum as well. thanks!

Comment: ive checked and doubled checked and when i added DISTINCT to the sum it worked as well.

Comment: Note that you want to use the distinct key of the table in the count(distinct) - it seems you are using the user_id, which would always return a count of 1. Also, using 'distinct' inside the SUM() may seem to work, but it's actually only summing distinct amounts. If you have two orders with the same amount (for the same user), they won't get counted correctly.

Comment: ahh i see. well, i tried the query you have above and both count_addr and count_cards return 0

Comment: It looks like I mistyped some of your field names - which should give you an error, not a 0 (unless you have the fields I specified, and they point to something else). Your original query used 'usera_userid' and 'userc_userid', and I've specified 'usera_id' and 'userc_id'. Interesting naming convention you've got there.

Comment: got it. usera_id should be usera_userid and userc_id should be userc_userid. 

i see you like my fancy naming skills :p

Comment: @Doug: you could push the `LEFT JOIN orders ON ...` to a subquery (or 2 here) in teh `SELECT` list as you have done with the others. So, no need for `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @ypercube - I try to avoid subqueries where possible. MySQL seems to handle them poorly. I would always recommend performance testing, but I find that most of the time, subqueries are slower (and sometimes MUCH slower) than using group by.  I just did a test across a 270,000 record table using a set of 30 unique fields, counting the occurrences of each key. For the group by, it took 0.3 seconds the first time, and 0.0 seconds each subsequent time (once cached). The subquery took 3 full seconds each time.

Comment: Yes, you are right, and one has to test in any case. This problem could also be solved the other way, by joining the `users` to 3 subqueries that use JOIN and GROUP BY to the 3 tables. That would be probably the best way for performance.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested before:

```sql
count(distinct(orders.order_id)) as count_orders
```

And you could use:

```sql
(select sum(order_total) from orders where user_id = users.user_id) as sum_ordertotal
```